# Why is gulp injecting the css styles in the wrong directory?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am pretty new to Gulp. 
I'm working in a project that uses gulp and when I run gulp serve in the console and make some changes in my sass files, gulp inject the styles in the wrong directory:

```
[09:39:26] gulp-ruby-sass: write ../../../../../cjdelgado/AppData/Local/Temp/gulp-ruby-sass/index.css
[09:39:26] gulp-ruby-sass: write ../../../../../cjdelgado/AppData/Local/Temp/gulp-ruby-sass/index.css.
```

And this doesn't happen to my coworkers.

Could this be happening because my node or ruby versions? 
Can I change that path manually? And, Should I change it?

This is my gulp file:

```
/**
 *  Welcome to your gulpfile!
 *  The gulp tasks are split into several files in the gulp directory
 *  because putting it all here was too long
 */

'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var gulp = require('gulp');

/**
 *  This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory
 *  in order to load all gulp tasks
 */
fs.readdirSync('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});


/**
 *  Default task clean temporaries directories and launch the
 *  main optimization build task
 */
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

And I am running it from: 
/c/Users/cjdelgado/Documents/Gitlab/register

And this is my gulp/inject.js file, wich I think the problem could be solved from:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var _ = require('lodash');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('inject-reload', ['inject'], function() {
  browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('inject', ['scripts', 'styles'], function () {
  var injectStyles = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.css'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/vendor.css')
  ], { read: false });

  var injectScripts = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.module.js'),
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.spec.js'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.mock.js'),
  ])
  .pipe($.angularFilesort()).on('error', conf.errorHandler('AngularFilesort'));

  var injectOptions = {
    ignorePath: [conf.paths.src, path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')],
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(injectStyles, injectOptions))
    .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, injectOptions))
    .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));
});
```

Comment: You'll need to post your gulp file and a tree/diagram of where you're running gulp from.

Comment: this is where your path is configured:
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));
If it's gonna solve the problem - change it!

Comment: Hey any updated on this or you able to resolve this out as I faced this same issue on windows VM.